# Create a function with a self-referencing generic able to infer a generic type from the values in the object passed to the function itself

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, playwright

I am trying to build a function that receives an object as parameter, and each key of this object is a function that receives as first parameter the object itself. Check the following code:

```ts
type TestFixture<ReturnT, ExtraArgs = {}> = (args: ExtraArgs, use: (val: ReturnT) => void) => void

const createTestFixture = <T, ExtraArgs = {}>(fn: TestFixture<T, ExtraArgs>) => fn

const a = <T extends { [K in keyof T]: TestFixture<any, T> }>(x: T): T => x

type TestA = number
type TestB = string

const res = a({
    testA: createTestFixture<TestA>((d, use) => {
        // how to make this work? - testB should have type string, which is the type testB result resolves to (the type passed to use)
        d.testB
        use(1)
    }),
    testB: createTestFixture<TestB>((d, use) => {
        // how to make this work? - testA should have type number, which is the type testA result resolves to (the type passed to use)
        d.testA
        use('abc')
    }),
})
```

I wanted `d.testA` to have the same type the `testA` property resolves to (`TestA`), but it seems that TypeScript does not support those self-referencing generics. The type of `d` in the above functions is set to an empty object, `{}`.

Is there any way to make this work?

[Here is a TypeScript playground with the above code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

For background information, I'm trying to create a helper to create Playwright test fixtures.

*I have no idea how to make this title better, if you have a better one feel free to edit it*

Comment: COuld you please explain why `d.testB` in `testA: createTestFixture<TestA>((d, use)` should have a type `string`?

Comment: @captain-yossarian because that is the value being passed to `use` in the `testB` function. 

I want `d.testB` to have the type of `TestB` (notice this is the generic value passed to the createTestFixture` generic of the `testB` property.

Comment: if you want to infer in such way, you need to return `use('abs')` instead of just calling it. DOes it work for you? I mean if I return calling `use` from the method

Comment: @captain-yossarian it does not, as this can be used like a middleware, when you call `use` you are passing the execution control back to the caller and the next middleware are going to be called, including the tests. You may want to run something after `use` is called, so you are not supposed to return anything.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to infer it in such representation. TypeScript is very limited in infering mutations